# Correct way to write out a date range in German

Tags: standard-german, time

What is the best way to write out a date range in German?

For example, something takes place on `05. September 2015` which is how I've come accustomed to seeing it in Germany. I'm not sure as to why the point is used after the number? When writing out a date range, my colleague sent me this:

```
05.–30. September 2015
```

Why do we use the points? Typographically it looks redundant. Just want to know the reasoning as `05–30 September 2015` looks cleaner, but not sure how to present this to my German native colleagues who are stern about this topic.

Comment: closely related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2101/what-is-the-best-format-to-use-when-writing-out-dates

Comment: These are actually two questions. Do you mind splitting the two questions and create a separate question for the "point" thing? Anyway, regard the point as reflection of the conjugated form:  "5" is "fünf", "5." is "fünfter". See http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Punkt.html?lang=de#Anchor-Der-51540

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because the point of the point (pun intended) is to give the [ordinal number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics)) instead of the [cardinal number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number_(linguistics)).

Interestingly enough, English *does* use ordinal numbers for days when writing "on the **fifth** of May", or "May **5th**" but omits the ordinal marker for dates like 05-05. 
German is more consistent as it *always* uses the '.' (Except for the YYYY-MM-DD format which is seldom used in day-to-day writing.) Please note that if you write the month as a number, it's ordinal as well: 05.05.

So your collegue could have written "05. - 30. September" *or* "05. - 30.09."

Answer (score 13):

We use the point to get the *ordinal*, not *cardinal* number. Compare:

> der 1. Platz (**=der *erste* Platz**)
>
> Straße des 17. Juni (**=des *siebzehnten* Juni**)

That's why we *must* use the point in dates.

According to the range - these would be some common ways of giving a time period:

> 5. - 30. September 2015
>
> vom 5. bis (zum) 30. September 2015
>
> vom 5. - 30. September 2015 *(which I personally don't like because you mix a preposition with symbolic dash character, but it's very common)*