# Ursprung des Punktes bei Ordinalzahlen

Tags: etymology, history, punctuation, numbers, typography

Als ich [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24381/correct-way-to-write-out-a-date-range-in-german) gelesen habe, wurde mir klar, dass ich keine Ahnung habe, warum wir im Deutschen Ordinalzahlen mit Punkten schreiben. In anderen Sprachen wird das ja anders gehandhabt, wobei man sich oft an der Aussprache orientiert und Buchstaben nach- oder hochstellt:

- **Englisch:** Nach- oder hochgestelltes *st, nd, rd, th* wie in 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup>.
- **Französisch:** Hochgestelltes *er, re, e* wie in 1<sup>er</sup>, 1<sup>re</sup>, 2<sup>e</sup>.
- **Italienisch:** Hochgestelltes *o, a* wie in 1<sup>o</sup>, 1<sup>a</sup>.
- **Deutsch:** Nachgestellter Punkt wie in 1., 2., 3.

**Meine Fragen:**
Woher kommt die deutschsprachige Praxis mit dem Punkt? Wann hat man denn damit angefangen? Ist das ein deutsches Phänomen oder wurde es aus einer anderen Sprache übernommen?

---

<sup>Zuvor hatte ich Spanisch und Italienisch zum hochgestellten *o* und *a* sortiert. Wie in den Kommentaren angemerkt wurde, steht im Spanischen aber zwischen hochgestellter Endung und Zahlzeichen ein Punkt. Auf der Wikipediaseite [Ordinal indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator#Usage) steht hierzu:</sup>

> <sup>As with other abbreviations in Spanish, the ordinal numbers have a period ".", which is placed before the superscript letter(s).</sup>

<sup>Dieser Satz würde nahelegen, dass (zumindest im Spanischen) Ordinalzahlen als Abkürzungen empfunden werden/wurden. Mir persönlich erscheint es aber befremdlich, dass gerade die Zahlzeichen für Ordinalzahlen eine Abkürzung darstellen sollen, die Zahlzeichen für Kardinalzahlen jedoch nicht.</sup>

Comment: Keine Antwort, aber es fällt auf, dass die deutsche Schreibweise unter den gezeigten Beispielen die einzige ist, bei der das Suffix nie angepasst werden muss, weder abhängig von der Zahl noch von grammatikalischen Eigenschaften des nachfolgenden Substantivs. Ich weiß leider nicht, ob das in irgendeiner Beziehung zur Entstehung der Schreibweise steht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: ... was dem Leser zusätzlich abverlangt, dass er weiss, wie er es lesen muss. Wobei, das könnte auch mit der Ursache zu tun haben, weil es ja auf den Fall ankommt: `Er ist 27. geworden.` und `Er wohnt im 27. Stock` muss man ja ganz anders lesen. Und bei Personen wird es richtig anspruchsvoll: `Er war mit Papst Johannes XXIII. zusammengetroffen.` (in dem Fall schreibt man den Punkt manchmal nichtmal).

Comment: @PMF: "Er ist 27 geworden." verwendet üblicherweise keine Ordinalzahl. Aber, ja, "Er wohnt im 27. Stock." und "Der 27. Stock ist der Stock, in dem er wohnt." wird schon mal unterschiedlich gesprochen. Gleiches gilt natürlich für die Verwendung von bestimmten und unbestimmten Artikeln.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Wenn er in einem Rennen aber den 27. Platz gemacht hat, ist er 27. geworden. ;-) Interessant finde ich auch, dass "1." nicht nur "erste(r/n/m/s)" bedeutet, sondern auch "erste*n*s".

Comment: Ich hatte bis jetzt immer gedacht, dass irgendwann aus einer (evtl. hochgestellten) Abkürzung der Endung aus Faulheit ein Punkt geworden ist, genauso wie sich das hochgestellte Umlaut-e zu einem Doppelpunkt vereinfacht hat. Aber das ist ein reiner Analogieschluss, ich habe entsprechende Manuskripte usw. nie gesehen.

Comment: Nachtrag: Mit z.B. [diesen Suchbegriffen](https://www.google.de/search?q="der+1te"+manuskript) finden sich bei Google Books diverse Fälle, wo in alten gedruckten Büchern die Abkürzungen kein Punkt ist, sondern in Buchstaben ausgeführt wird. Was auch immer das bedeutet.

Comment: Im Spanischen existiert eine Kombination aus Punkt und hochgestelltem ª bzw. º. Zum Beispiel: 5.º / 5.ª – Vergleiche: http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Número_ordinal – Und nach der englischen Wikipedia ist der Punkt keine Besonderheit: "In Basque, Bosnian / Croatian / Serbian, Czech, Danish, Estonian, Faroese, German, Hungarian, Icelandic, Latvian, Norwegian, Polish, Slovak, Slovene, Turkish, among other languages, a period or full stop is written after the numeral." Vergleiche: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator

Comment: Bezüglich dem in den Kommentaren genannten Beispiel am Papst, könnte das hier vielleicht auch von Interesse/Bedeutung sein: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/46783/16833

Comment: Eine weitere Kuriosität, die mir gerade einfällt: Bei Variablen verwendet man eher Suffixe als den Punkt (die *n-te Wurzel*).

Comment: @Chris: Mein Beispiel meinte den 27. Platz. Bin gar nicht drauf gekommen, dass man das auch anders lesen könnte (von daher: Der Punkt macht jedenfalls einen Unterschied).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie es scheint, lässt sich der genaue Ursprung des Punktes in Ordnungszahlen nicht klären. Wie **Em1** festgestellt hat, handelt es sich dabei keinesfalls um eine Besonderheit des Deutschen, weil es in den Sprachen wie Bosnisch, Kroatisch, Serbisch, Tschechisch, Dänisch, Ungarisch, Slowakisch oder Türkisch ähnlich gehandhabt wird.

Nachdem ich ein wenig zum Thema geforscht habe, kann ich einige mögliche Entstehungserklärungen zusammenfassen:

**1.** Es ist *einfach so* passiert, genauso wie sich aus dem hochgestellten *e* für Umlaute zwei Punkte entwickelt haben. Genauso gut hätte sich daraus ein Strich entwickeln können oder aber würden wir das hochgestellte *e* bis heute schreiben. Irgendjemand hat damit angefangen, um Ordinalzahlen von Kardinalzahlen zu unterscheiden und es hat sich durchgesetzt.

**2.** Der hochgestellte Kreis **°**, wie er in vielen Sprachen, auch im Lateinischen, im Gebrauch war, evolvierte mit der Zeit zu einem Kreis neben der Zahl: **2o Platz** und reduzierte sich mit der Zeit zum gewöhnlichen Punkt.

**3.** Die Art und Weise, wie wir Daten angeben, z.B. **12.06.1850**, was ja als ***der zwölfte sechste*** ausgesprochen wird, war maßgebend dafür, dass diese Schreibweise auch auf sonstige Angaben von Ordinalzahlen übertragen wurde.

Um den Ursprung wirklich genau zu klären, müsste man vermutlich die europäische Literatur durchforsten und die Schreibweise von Ordinalzahlen genau analysieren und zurückverfolgen. Das sprengt aber den Rahmen von German.SE.

Comment: Du schreibst, dass du *"ein wenig zum Thema geforscht"* hast. Könntest du diesen Prozess bitte beschreiben? (Hast du dir einige Originalquellen angeschaut? Oder hast du Theorien/Hypothesen in Sekundärliteratur gefunden?) - Die dritte Hypothese finde ich besonders interessant, weil in der Antwort zu der Frage, die mich zu dieser Frage hier motiviert hat, gerade die Erklärung umgekehrt war: Wir schreiben Daten so, weil Tag und Monat als Ordinalzahlen ausgesprochen werden, die ja mit einem Punkt geschrieben werden. (Henne-Ei-Problem)

Comment: Eher Sekundärliteratur, ich habe mir die Quellen aber nicht notiert. Hätte ich eine stichhaltige Begründung oder Ursprungsangabe gefunden, hätte ich sie gerne angegeben; da aber alles sehr vage war und nur Vermutungen angestellt wurden, habe ich auf Quellenangabe verzichtet und stattdessen das Gelesene mit eigenen Worten zusammengefasst.